# Is it possible to add inline images using low-level Appengine Email API? (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I'm trying to add an embedded/inline image to an html email I'm sending in my appengine app. Can the low level API do this? From the javadocs can't find any methods that could do this. Usually this is done using multipart mime parts and using the Content-Id of the image in the html part.

Ideally I'd like to generate an email message like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.50.75.3 with HTTP; Thu, 23 Feb 2012 20:15:34 -0800 (PST)
Date: Thu, 23 Feb 2012 20:15:34 -0800
Delivered-To: aleem.mawani@gmail.com
Message-ID: <CAApOksvZBaU2WT7+=8B8J=CCN8KbxspbiisWcUEHHzQUVVWw4A@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: c
From: Foo <foo@gmail.com>
To: Foo <foo@gmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=e89a8f3b9b051e124104b9ae03fb

--e89a8f3b9b051e124104b9ae03fb
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=e89a8f3b9b051e123604b9ae03fa

--e89a8f3b9b051e123604b9ae03fa
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

[image: Inline image 1]

--e89a8f3b9b051e123604b9ae03fa
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<img src="cid:ii_135ad92205fc1ace" alt="Inline image 1"><br>

--e89a8f3b9b051e123604b9ae03fa--
--e89a8f3b9b051e124104b9ae03fb
Content-Type: image/png; name="logo.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <ii_135ad92205fc1ace>
X-Attachment-Id: ii_135ad92205fc1ace

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAAh0lEQVR42u3ZsQnAIBBGYVtHShVI
7ViprASXcw8HMCckEGyTkB98xWsE4WvOwnMhBG/tVrGaSOU0+Q5MVhMtdWAVBlY3HCyW+7nlbhqB
TiGAAAECBAhwMqB0AN8ANuUkgQzJvEPy1WP75C5AgAABAgQ4GXATAK4DUP8LOAsD87WGiIJriGj5
AwiiiyDxmymtAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
--e89a8f3b9b051e124104b9ae03fb--
```

Answer (score 0):

Neve done it but it seems that it can be done:

See the [multipart support](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail.html#Multi_Part_Messages) via Javamail on how to add html body and attachments.

You can add an image attachment with [`MimeBodyPart`](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html) and add [custom headers](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#addHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (`Content-ID`).

Comment: Unfortunately, appengine removes the Content-ID header of the image part of the message. Sending HTML emails with images from appengine is something that many people want, but Google does not make it possible.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the javaMail multipart implementation (see comments at the bottom): http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=965
Try using low-level API, though you'd need do do multipart by hand.